# Load Confguration Documents

Tags: ravendb

I have a question.
In ravenDB documentation and in the document modeling chapter, Author say that it's better that we use configuration document for reference data. for example for city document we can create doucment:
"NY":"New York",
"WS": "Washington"
....

Now how can read this document from client API? The Load method is generic: Load. that mean we need to c# class for that. but I don't know how to define this c# class and how load this document in C#
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start by going to https://demo.ravendb.net/ 
 and learn from:

**Create Related Documents** h[ttps://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/create-related-documents](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/create-related-documents)

and
**Load Related Documents** https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/load-related-documents

Go through the Walkthrough steps